# Executing custom validation before record created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I want to execute a custom validation before the record is created?

It looks as if this is the right method: before_validation_on_create.  For example:

```
before_validation_on_create :custom_validation
```

But am not sure.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I see there is: validate_on_create.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

before_validation_on_create hooks happen before validation on create… but they aren't validations themselves.

What you probably want to do is use `validate` and a private method which adds to the error array. like this:

```
class IceCreamCone

  validate :ensure_ice_cream_is_not_melted, :before => :create

  private
    def ensure_ice_cream_is_not_melted
      if ice_cream.melted?
        errors.add(:ice_cream, 'is melted.')
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: I like your example in particular.

Comment: This example has me giggling like a little girl at the office

Answer (score 34):

In rails 3

```
before_validation_on_create :do_something
```

has been replaced with:

```
before_validation :do_something, :on => :create
```

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question of running custom validations before creation, but it answers the question I came here with.

Answer (score 13):

The following worked for me in Rails 5:

`validate :custom_validation_method, :on => :create`

Running

`validate :custom_validation_method, :before => :create`

gave me following error:

```
Unknown key: :before. Valid keys are: :on, :if, :unless, :prepend.
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a great resource here for information on callbacks and the order they happen in:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It points to very clear documentation describing the solution to the OP's problem, and better understanding of validations in general.

Comment: It got downvoted because it's not an answer, it's just a link to an external reference.